# New Home Build Tar Paper/Vapor Barrier on Part of Garage Wall Interior that is an Exterior Wall

Tags: walls, insulation, garage, vapor-barrier

Had a question, have a new house being built in Arizona. Will attach a couple of photos but do you know why they would put a paper / barrier on the interior of part of the wall and not the rest? The first photo is an exterior facing wall and only part has it. Then the other parts of wall with the paper in second photos is an interior wall as you can tell it’s insulated.

[image: RVGarage Exterior Facing Wall]
[image: Half is interior wall hence insulation but still more barrier]
[image]

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Is there a difference on the other side of those walls.  Half being part of the house and part just on the outside?  The paper should be part of a moisture/draft control system.  Did not think they still use it for walls.

Comment: So the exterior is stucco, so I guess maybe code they only have to do certain parts with plywood. It could be just paper,foam, then wire mesh for stucco… builders these days really stick to code to avoid an extra 200 bucks…